# New laptop runs hot and has low battery life

Tags: battery, fan

my Asus laptop runs super hot on ubuntu 18.4, all iam doing is some simple coding and web browsing (not even watching movies).
My laptop always gets hot as if iam gaming on it on windows (duel boot).however the fans do kick in, but it drains my battery life like crazy.

i read through some posts on the internet and on google, that it might be related to the drivers installed, i have installed some programs to monitor the laptops thermals and lower them, but it hasnt helped much.

CPU : Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2592 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)

GPU : NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070  /  Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630

Comment: It's helpful to provide your laptop make and model. Then others with the same model can post an answer.

Comment: Please go to "system settings" and then click on "details" and please edit your question and include the information listed for "processor" and "graphics". Thanks!

Comment: I would check in the Task Manager if there is any process consuming a lot of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing same issue on windows and linux both operating systems, you should go to service center to solve this issue.

Comment: i dont have these problems on windows, just on ubuntu